# Apache Flink: How to query a relational database with the Table API?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

The following code snippet is taken from this [blog post](https://flink.apache.org/news/2017/04/04/dynamic-tables.html):

```
val sensorTable = ??? // can be a CSV file, Kafka topic, database, or ...

// register the table source
tEnv.registerTableSource("sensors", sensorTable)
```

I would like to read data from a relational database. Does Flink have a `TableSource` for JDBC databases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In its current version (1.4.0, Dec. 2017), Flink does not provide a built-in `TableSource` to ingest data from a relational database.

However, there is a [`JDBCInputFormat`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.4/flink-connectors/flink-jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/io/jdbc/JDBCInputFormat.java) that can be used. You can either

- use it to read the data from the database using the DataSet API and [register the `DataSet` as a `Table`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/table/common.html#register-a-datastream-or-dataset-as-table) or
- [implement a `JdbcTableSource`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/table/sourceSinks.html#define-a-tablesource) that wraps the `JdbcInputFormat`. A simple implementation of a `JdbcTableSource` should be easy to achieve. Implementing support for parallel reads, projection or filter push-down, requires more effort.

Comment: Please share if any scala reference code for this . I am using Flink 1.3 version .

Comment: [Starting with Flink 1.12 the DataSet API has been soft deprecated.](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/dataset/overview/)